# Phonegap API list grab ID on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I created an API list with href link and each of them has a different ID. The issue I'm having it's how to store the ID to get it for the next page. I create a click function but it's not currently working not sure why.

```
var indexdirectory ='<table class="member-list"><tbody><tr><td><a id="member-list-link"  member-id="'+response[i].id+'" href="member.html?id=222" >'+imagedirectory+'</a>'; $("#indexdirectory").append(indexdirectory);
            getmedia(urlmedia);

        }

    },

        error: function() {
    console.log('nope');                
    }
}); 

$( "#member-list-link" ).live('click',function(){

    alert("test");
});
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?  `live()` was removed in v1.9

Comment: I'm using the newest one. I also try click()function but nothing. I have been trying different methods been finding online but no luck. Is it possible because it has 10 #member-list taglines?

Comment: Uh, yeah, id's can't be repeated.  That would be an issue.

Comment: okay, what's a good way to confront this issue?

Comment: Use a class instead.  Classes can be repeated.  And what you want for the binding is a delegate binding.  http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/